# Delete item from DynamoDB php

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

Can't seem to get my head round deleting items from dynamo db in php.

I would like to delete all items with a specific user_id. Firstly I get all the users items like so:

```
    $users = $this->ddb->getIterator('Query', array(
        'TableName'     => 'users',
        'KeyConditions' => array(
            'user_id' => array(
                'AttributeValueList' => array(
                    array('N' => Config::get('user_id'))
                ),
                'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ'
            )
        )
    ));
```

I then iterate over the object and delete each one:

```
    foreach($users as $user) {
        $this->ddb->deleteItem([
            'TableName' => 'users',
            'Key' => [
                'user_id' => ['N' => $user['user_id']['S']]
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

No matter how I try it I get:

```
The provided key element does not match the schema
```

Can anyone shed some insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The provided key element does not match the schema.

The `user_id` does not seem to be a part of your table's schema. You are including it in the `'Key'` parameter of `deleteItem`, which is incorrect. You can only delete items by their key.

When you get items from your query iterator, you need to retrieve the values that are a part of the table's key, and then specify those in the `deleteItem`'s `'Key'` parameter.

Comment: Cool, so how do I find the tables key, the query iterator doesn't bring back anything to do with a "Key" from what I can tell

Comment: Do a `describeTable` call or look in the AWS console

Comment: The describeTable was helpful to figure out the correct structure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the top one you have user_id as a number (N) and on the bottom one you have user_id as a string (S) so my guess is that Dynamo is just flagging that there's no user_id of that type on the schema.

Comment: Actual spelling mistake in post. Fixed. But obviously still doesn't work.